# My intranet website is not accessible by few users

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, iis-6

I have an internal IIS 6 server hosting a website.  I have the site set to integrated windows authentication and it works fine.  What is wrong after recent release is that 5 windows machines that are not able to access the website. Other users from different regions are able to access it as usual.

When I used Fiddler to see what is happening, the website is keep on loading and fiddler shows that 401.1 and 401.2 errors. It says that user name password is wrong. From what I can tell all of the settings in IE are identical to the other 40 or 50 machines that are working fine.  Has anyone run into anything like this before?

Comment: are they(new machine) on the same domain?

Comment: yes, and before the release, they were able to access it